# An algorithm for grouping table of contents items

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have been tasked with generating a table of contents file based on some data structures. The data looks like this:

```
class ToCItem
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> path;
    public int page;
}
```

For sample data like this:

```
ToCItem
{
    path = { 1 => "chapter 1" },
    page = 1;
}

ToCItem
{
    path = { 1 => "chapter 1", 2 => "section 1" },
    page = 2;
}

ToCItem
{
    path = { 1 => "chapter 1", 2 => "section 2" },
    page = 6;
}

ToCItem
{
    path = { 1 => "chapter 1", 2 => "section 2", 3 => "image" },
    page = 7;
}

ToCItem
{
    path = { 1 => "summary" },
    page = 8;
}
```

I need an output like this:

```
.chapter 1: 1
..section 1: 2
..section 2: 6
...image: 7
.summary: 8
```

(dots are tabs)

I can't figure out any algorithm to do this. My first thought was to group the items by each of the hierarchy levels and do something like this:

```
foreach (var group in paths.GroupBy(p => p.Path[1]))
            {
                if (group.Key != null)
                {
                    Console.Write("\t");
                    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
                }
                var grouped2 = group.GroupBy(g => g.Path.ContainsKey(2) ? g.Path[2] : null);
                foreach (var group2 in grouped2)
                {
                    if (group2.Key != null)
                    {
                        {
                            Console.Write("\t\t");
                            Console.WriteLine(group2.Key);
                        }
                    }
                    var grouped3 = group.GroupBy(g => g.Path.ContainsKey(3) ? g.Path[3] : null);
                    foreach (var group3 in grouped3)
                    {
                        if (group3.Key != null)
                        {
                            Console.Write("\t\t\t");
                            Console.WriteLine(group3.Key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But then I cen get only hierarchies and not actual paths. Also this doesn't scale with deeper hierarchies. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: No, it is not. I wish I have had homework like this, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'd love to put together a recursive solution for you, I don't think it's necessary. It looks like you should just be able to do

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = paths
    .OrderBy(toc => toc.page)
    .Select(toc =>
        /* one tab per depth */
        new string('\t', toc.path.Count) +
        /* title of item */
        toc.path.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Key).Select(kvp => kvp.Value).First() +
        ": " +
        /* page number */
        toc.page);
```

Note that the title line would be *much* neater if your `path` property was just a `List<string>` (or `string` array) rather than a dictionary!

Edit: As Dennis' answer below has noted, as long as your dictionary keys are consistent, you can use

```
toc.path[toc.path.Count]
```

to get the title rather than doing a sort-and-select as I have done above.

Comment: This doesn't handle out-of-order pages, but I guess that's not how tables of contents are supposed to work, so I'm going with this.

Answer (score 3):

+1 to Rawling's answer. If you don't want to use LINQ, here's an old-fashioned method to do the same:

```
public string ItemToString(ToCItem item)
{
    var length = item.path.Count;

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(new string('\t', length));
    builder.Append(item.path[length] + ": ");
    builder.Append(item.page);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I've stolen your method of getting the title from the dictionary, I hope you don't mind :p

Comment: @Rawling I've borrowed your method to create the tabs :-)